# How to make a multivariate function take a matrix as input and return a vector as output?

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, vector

Sorry if this question has been asked to death. Suppose I define a function like this

```
function out = myfun (x)
out = x(1).^2 + x(2).^2;
end
```

Give a matrix such as

```
X = unifrnd(0,1,100,2);
```

I want to get a vector Y such that for i =1,2,...100,

```
Y(i) = myfun(X(i,:));
```

Is there any function I can use to avoid involving loop?

Comment: Will `X` always be 2-columns sized?

Comment: @BillBokeey Sorry, should be X = unifrnd(0,1,100,2);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't `unifrnd(100,2)` a problem here?

> *unifrnd Random arrays from continuous uniform distribution.*
>
> R = unifrnd(A,B) returns an array of random numbers chosen from the
>   continuous uniform distribution on the interval from A to B.  The size
>   of R is the common size of A and B if both are arrays.  If either
>   parameter is a scalar, the size of R is the size of the other
>   parameter.
>
> R = unifrnd(A,B,M,N,...) or R = unifrnd(A,B,[M,N,...])
>   returns an M-by-N-by-... array.

---

## Now to answer the question...

With the function changed to work on the columns of the input...
This is relatively simple to do with the elementwise power and indexing the columns...

```
function out = myfun (X)
out = X(:,1).^2 + X(:,2).^2;
end
```

usage...

```
lower_lim = 0
upper_lim = 1
X = unifrnd(lower_lim,upper_lim,100,2)
Y = myfun(X)
```

Comment: Sorry about my mistake. Your solution totally works out. Thanks.

Comment: no worries, one little extra comment: if the entire array is from the same distribution `unifrnd` is a bit overkill, just `rand(100,2)` would suffice for a range of 0-1 or with scaling to min-max `min+rand(100,2)*(max-min)`